# UIPopoverController not working if called from pushed ViewController

Tags: ios, popover

I am using FPPopover library to show popover. it was working when using model presenting but it is not working in pushed viewcontroller.
here is used code :

```
GettingDataForPOPOver *popoverContent = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"POPOVER"];
    popoverContent.delegate = self;
    popoverContent.Tag = 0;
    popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:popoverContent];
    popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(200,210);
    popover.border = NO;
    popover.tint = FPPopoverWhiteTint;
     popover.delegate = self;
    //[popover.navigationController pushViewController:popover animated:NO];
    [popover presentPopoverFromView:okButton];
```

also this one not working :

```
GettingDataForPOPOver *popoverContent = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"POPOVER"];

    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popoverContent];

    //popoverContent.delegate = self;
    popoverContent.Tag = 0;
    FPPopoverController *popoverr = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:nc];
    popoverr.delegate = self;
    popoverr.tint = FPPopoverDefaultTint;
    popoverr.contentSize = CGSizeMake(200,210);
    [popoverr presentPopoverFromView:okButton];

        CGRect nc_bar_frame = nc.navigationBar.frame;
        nc_bar_frame.origin.y = 0;
        nc.navigationBar.frame = nc_bar_frame;
```

Comment: Rather than writing initWithViewController just write init and check.

    popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:popoverContent];

Comment: @Ashutosh thank you for your replay but still not working

Comment: I'm having same problem.. Is there any approach so far?